# How to get my class to appear in Aptana's autocomplete?

Tags: php, class, autocomplete, aptana

I'm searching for a possibility to add my own classes to the Aptana autocompletion for my project. At the moment I have one project file with a directory "class" with class files in it, which will be inserted with "require_once" in my php project.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 11):

File->New->PHP Project-> Project Explorer ( new project )

right click on [YOUR PROJECT] in "Project Explorer" -> Properties

You will see "Properties for [YOUR PROJECT]" window

Project Natures -> PHP (checkbox)
and click "Make Primary" button.

OK, OK

Project will be reindexed and your classes will be available

Answer (score 1):

Any class existing in your project (assuming it's a PHP project) will be included in the code assist when you start typing a letter. The studio does not restrict the code assist proposals to the `include` or `require` tags, so you'll need to make sure that you include anything that your script is using.

In case you would like to add external directories (frameworks, and such), you can attach it by following the instructions at the [Studio's Wiki](http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/PHP+Development#PHPDevelopment-ExternalLibraries/Frameworks)

Answer (score 1):

This solved it for me:

http://www.liquidcomposition.com/devblog/?p=89

In short:
Add your project to:
Window > Preferences > Aptana > Editors > PHP > PHP Libraries
And make sure your project is a PHP-project:
Rightclick project > Properties > Project Natures

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this in this way: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13871388/1453233

Try to find out how to install:
"org.eclipse.php.core.PHPNature" Nature with PDT plugin.