# Aptana Studio 3 code completion / assist not working for Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii, code-completion, aptana3

I just started development with Aptana Studio 3 and Yiiframework. Since Aptana Studio 3 already supports code completion for PHP and Yiiframework does faciliate correct use of PHPDoc comments and return types, I assumed that calling

```
$app = Yii::app();
$app->...
```

should pop up content assist with methods and fields of the `CApplication` class. But I only see an empty popup window containing '*No proposal*'. The same happens when accessing the application object directly using

```
Yii::app()-> // empty code assist window
```

When I declare the type of the `$app` variable explicitly, code assist pops up correct:

```
/**
 * @var CApplication
 */
$app = Yii::app();
$app-> // code assist pops up with correct content
```

I don't have included yiilite.php - this file is stripped from my framework directory. Code assist works, but not as expected.

Is this a bug, or a missing feature? Can anybody else confirm this behaviour of Aptana  Studio 3? Is there any workaround?

Thanks,
David

Comment: Yii framework is inside the same Aptana project. I also have cleaned project cache multiple times with _'Project'->'Clean'_ without success.

Comment: Found some Youtube video addressing exactly the same problem. Seems to be an missing Aptana Studio 3 feature? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5fPgDCXdqzY

Comment: Aptana Studio 2 supports these PHPDoc comments and also code completion. It seems this is some kind of Aptana 3 bug (or a missing feature?)

Answer (score 4):

It is also important to explicitly set the 'Project Nature' to (include) PHP. Project->properties->Project Natures

Answer (score 2):

Follow the [steps given here](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/PHP+Development#PHPDevelopment-AttachingPHPResources) and the code completion should work properly.

Answer (score 1):

The other methods mentioned here will not work for YII code assist.

See if this helps:

1. Start with a PHP Project (Or for an existing project: Configure -> Add PHP support )
2. Add the YII framework to the build path like below.

PHP Include path -> Libraries -> Add External source folder -> Select the 'framework' folder from the YII framework unzipped

Also point #5 from Arek about adding the Eclipse PHP nature helped me too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how exactly I did this, but:

1. Delete already existing project.
2. Install PDT plugin for
   Aptana by "Help->Install New Software"
3. Restart Aptana Studio
4. Create again new project and check out in project properties You have new "Nature" called
   "org.eclipse.php.core.PHPNature" as a primary.
5. Uncheck "PHP"
   Nature, only "org.eclipse..." should be checked.

Only with this nature I see all classes, methods etc...
With orginial aptana's "PHP" Nature it was impossible.

"org.eclipse.php.core.PHPNature" is solution for this.

EDIT: PDT might not be required for Aptana since it has PHP support built-in

Answer (score 0):

http://firas-vision.com/aptana-yii-2/

please check this solution worked for me , no new plugin , it is just a code fix for com.aptana.editor.php.jar plugin

I pulled a request to change on Aptana git , hope they will include this fix in the next release

Answer (score 0):

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/45905-aptana-yii-support-autocomplete/ this seems to have helped with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. unzip your yii source tarbal, import the framework directory as a project on your workspace
2. Navigate to Your project Explorer, and right click on the project you wish to support Yii's autocomplete on  and select "Properties"
3. A  project properties' dialog page will be displayed, on the right side of the dialog there is a tree select the child labelled "PHP Buildpath", on your right click on "Add"  and add the "Framework Directory " as part of your  build path
4. Apply Changes and Press OK to submit the changes. Now try to create a class that extends any of the Yii Core Classes it should autocomplete successfully.

Enjoy Yourself