# Aptana Code Assist in PHP with require_once files

Tags: php, aptana, code-assist

I've seen many topics on Aptana Code Assist not working with include files due to space in the include statement, etc but most were listed as "Resolved" Well, I'm trying to simply `require_once` a file with php/html in it and declare a variable and I try to trigger *Code Assist* by beginning to type the variable name in a file that uses the require file and it doesn't pick up the previously defined variable.

```
<?php

$test = 1;

?>
<div>
Some HTML
</div>
```

..next script

```
<?php

require_once('thefile.php');

$test2 = $tes.. // No Code Assist :/
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to wait until some aptana user joins by I suppose... .

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244722/how-to-get-my-class-to-appear-in-aptanas-autocomplete

Comment: @SteAp - Thank You! That link worked perfectly. You just make sure "PHP" is checked in the Project Natures section of your project's properties.