# Aptana 3 and Codeigniter external library autocomplete

Tags: php, codeigniter, aptana

I've already tweaked my buildpath to autocomplete the native CI library but i can't autocomplete external library like templates and stuff. i've followed the instructions based from both http://taggedzi.com/articles/display/autocomplete-eclipse-codeigniter-2 and http://r15ch13.de/2011/03/autocomplete-in-aptana-3-for-codeigniter-2/ both are really helpful sites, just an info for you people out there, but one problem is that, i can't autocomplete external libraries, i've tweaked the base code to include that but it does nothing.

Anyone of you have tried tweaking autocomplete for external CI library e.g template..etc. please do share

Comment: Adding the library as shown in your second link should work, but you should also be able to download the library you want and include the files in your files and Aptana will treat it like your code: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244722/how-to-get-my-class-to-appear-in-aptanas-autocomplete)

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried what you have mentioned, but used https://github.com/hicode/codeigniter.ruble . It works pretty well. All you have to do is search about codeigniter rubles for Aptana.