# Import parent PHP file in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: php, import, autocomplete, include, aptana

In `Main.php` I have a variable `$SOME_VARIABLE` and I also `include('Sub.php')`

When the script runs, `Sub.php` of course has access to `$SOME_VARIABLE`, but when I'm in Aptana if I want to keep a reference to it (say, with autocompletion) Aptana doesn't know `$SOME_VARIABLE` exists in `Sub.php`.

Is there a (simple) way to reference `Main.php` from `Sub.php` so that Aptana knows `Sub.php` has access to `$SOME_VARIABLE`?

Comment: I found this answer on SO, I think it's worth trying: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8805212/3415104

Comment: @michal.hubczyk I searched quite a lot and never found anything (maybe I am bad at searching), but that link, while it did not solve the problem, ended up leading me to the answer I posted which did solve the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the project > Properties > Project Natures > Check `PHP`

I just needed to set my `Project Natures` correctly. I did have it set to `Ruby` and `Web - Primary`. When I checked `PHP` then it worked.

[image]

I probably don't need Ruby checked, but whatever.