# Aptana studio 3 include files with functions

Tags: php, aptana, aptana3

I'm using Aptana studio 3

If I create a php file and I add lets say 2 functions.
function test1() and function test2()

And I call function test1, then I see the info about this function, like what type of vars I need etc, that works fine.

But now I have this filestructure:

```
\ralph
 \inc
  functions.php # (here are the 2 test functions now)
 \projects
  \testwebsite
   index.php
```

in index.php I call this:

```
  include('../../inc/functions.php');
```

When I call the function test1
I don't see the details of hte function anymore.
is there a way to make this happen?

Ralph

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I was to quick asking this question:
answer can be found here:
[How to get my class to appear in Aptana's autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244722/how-to-get-my-class-to-appear-in-aptanas-autocomplete)
when you create a project make sure you check the mark php instead of web.
it works perfectly